# Mssql summary row using ROLLUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollup

I'm trying to generate a summary row using ROLLUP grouping,
Here is my query

```
 SELECT nic as NIC,branch_id,SUM(as_share),SUM(as_deposit) as as_deposit,SUM(as_credits) as as_credits,SUM(as_fixed) as as_fixed,SUM(as_ira) as as_ira,SUM(as_saviya) as as_saviya
    FROM As_Member_Account_Details
    GROUP BY nic,branch_id
    WITH ROLLUP
```

But it give me this output,

```
112233  1       30.00   0.00    0.00    50.00   0.00    0.00
112233  2       20.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
112233  3       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
112233  NULL    50.00   0.00    0.00    50.00   0.00    0.00
NULL    NULL    50.00   0.00    0.00    50.00   0.00    0.00
```

The row before the last row is unnecessary. Because there should be only 3 data rows + a summary row.  How can I eliminate that row

Comment: rollup generates row for evey grouped column. If you don't want these columns, you can insert this data to temp table and then delete unnecessary rows.

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved and dont post images.Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table t1
(
id int
)

insert into t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Grouping sets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427(v=sql.105).aspx) allows more granular control when cubeing data.

```
SELECT nic as NIC
     , branch_id,SUM(as_share)
     , SUM(as_deposit) as as_deposit
     , SUM(as_credits) as as_credits
     , SUM(as_fixed) as as_fixed
     , SUM(as_ira) as as_ira
     , SUM(as_saviya) as as_saviya
FROM As_Member_Account_Details
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((nic,branch_id),())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE_YourQuery AS
(
    SELECT nic as NIC,branch_id,SUM(as_share),SUM(as_deposit) as as_deposit,SUM(as_credits) as as_credits,SUM(as_fixed) as as_fixed,SUM(as_ira) as as_ira,SUM(as_saviya) as as_saviya
    FROM As_Member_Account_Details
    GROUP BY nic,branch_id
    WITH ROLLUP
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE_YourQuery
WHERE NOT (nic IS NOT NULL AND branch_id IS NULL)
```